# Is possible All options in react-checkbox-group

Tags: reactjs

```
<CheckboxGroup
  className={
    data.singleColumn
      ? styles.MultiCheckboxFieldSingle
      : styles.MultiCheckboxField
  }
  checkboxDepth={2} // This is needed to optimize the checkbox group
  name={input.name}
  value={input.value ? input.value.split(",") : []}
  checked={"true"}
  onChange={(val) => {
    input.onChange(val.join());
    console.log("val = ", val);
  }}
></CheckboxGroup>;
```

Comment: Please add more description . https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.